# loop through list with increment variable django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to go through the item of a list and get their length using increment variable and loop :

`words` is list and `data` is list of dictionary

```
{% for dict in data %}

<tr>
  <th>{{dict.Title}}</th>
  <th>{{ words.#increment variable should be here}}</th>
  <th>{{dict.Year}}</th>
  <th>{{dict.Type}}</th>
  <th><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/{{dict.imdbID}}/">{{dict.imdbID}} </a></th>
  <th>{{dict.random | stringformat:'d'}}</th>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `get their length using increment variable`? What is the expected output?

Comment: the output should be how many words in the Title

Comment: Is it related to `title` in `dict.title`?

Comment: i tried using this code but still won't work

'{% with forloop.counter0 as x %}  <th>{{words.x | length}}</th> {% endwith %}'

Comment: Do you mean you want to iterate through words inside this loop or you want to look up the index of a word based on the list of dictionaries?